# Directory List, holding every file name

Tags: python

Trying to create a list so each list value holds root directory and every file within that root directory, so each list value ends up looking like:

Z:\Clients\xxx\2. RAW Export\Area A\"a__bund-a8010.fls""a__bund-a9000.fls"

Comment: The question is not really clear. What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: Look into the os module. You can use either loops with os.listdir or os.walk, or probably others solutions within this module exist.

Comment: The input would give a location to a folder, which holds subfolders, I want the script to create a list for each subfolder, which will show the whole path and every file within the subfolder

Comment: Question not clear. What are you finding difficult? Getting the list of files, putting them in a dictionary, mapping them to folders? Please provide a [mcve], preferably with your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand the create a list for each sub-folder part.

If you're trying to

**1. Create a list that has all the directories including the root folder:** Create a list, then for every sub-folder, append it to the list

```
list = ["rootfolder directory"]
for subfolder in rootfolder:
   list.append(subfolder)
```

**2. Create a list that has all the directories which can be found by the name of root folder:** Above method will work by looking for the first item(Which will be the root directory). But I suggest using a dictionary

```
dirdic = {}  #First initialize a new dictionary
dirdic['rootfolder'] = [] #Make a new dictionary item
for subfolder in rootfolder:
   dirdic['rootfolder'].append(subfolder)
```

This way you can edit the list, create a new list object for every root directory, find list of subfolders by just searching the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have done it, Im sure it could be done alot nicer but:

```
import os

rootFolder = ("C:\\Users\\ALS_Surveying\\Desktop\\test folder")

# Creates a list of all subfolders
subFolderList = os.listdir(rootFolder)

# This create the full path to each subfolder
subFolderList2 = []
for a in subFolderList:
   temp = os.path.join(rootFolder,a)
   subFolderList2.append(temp)  

# How many subfolders in root
totalSubFolders = len(subFolderList)


# Creates a List holding a single value for all contents in each subfolder
fileList = []
stepper = 0
for fl in range(totalSubFolders):
   fileList.append(os.listdir(subFolderList2[stepper]))
   stepper = stepper + 1


# Create the final list holding the full path, root to files
filePathList = []
stepper = 0
for final in range(totalSubFolders):
   subFolderList2Var = str(subFolderList2[stepper])
   fileListVar = str(fileList[stepper])
   temp2 = os.path.join(subFolderList2Var,fileListVar)
   stepper = stepper + 1
   filePathList.append(temp2)
```

Love to hear your thoughts

Comment: You would better have posted this code inside your question – *if it does not work* (or if there is another problem with it, such as some side effects or reams of warnings) ... If you are looking for a code review, you could ask on [codereview.se] (read their [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first).